# Getting PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '[a particular path]' on calling os.remove

Tags: python, macos, permissions, operating-system, delete-file

In my code I've called `os.remove('[a particular path]')` in order to delete the file, however I'm getting `PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '[the same path]'` on calling os.remove. How do I give myself permissions?

Additional context: I'm on a Mac and I'd marked the python file as an executable using `chmod u+x file.py` and am running it through the terminal using `./file.py`. I'm also running it on iTerm2 and it has **full** disk access. Any answers would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a sanboxing problem, not permissions. The message for a permission problem is "Permission denied"

Comment: That depends on what's forbidding you from deleting the file. What're the permissions on the directory it's in? Is it being restricted by [TCC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673) and/or [SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368)? In any case, this isn't really a programming problem, so [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) is a better places to ask about things like this.